# Clockpicker displays and hides immediately after updating Chrome version to 73 on materializecss

Tags: jquery, materialize, popover

I have timepicker/clockpicker which is configured like this by materializecss (v0.100.2).

```
<label for="time">Time</label>
<input id="time" type="text" class="timepicker">

$('.timepicker').pickatime({
   default: 'now'
});
```

When we click on the text field the clockpicker modal opens, but immediately it gets closed. 
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/evQxPy

> This happens after I have updated my chrome version to 73

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chrome Update 73 - Materialize CSS JS trigger error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55147819/chrome-update-73-materialize-css-js-trigger-error)

Comment: This is a regression in Chrome 73. We have released pickadate 3.6.1 which should resolve this.

See https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=941910 for the regression in Chrome.

Comment: @DanielRuf we use only materialize.js not pickadate.js. So how do we fix it on materialize.js? Thanks

Comment: materialize uses a customized version of pickadate. See https://github.com/amsul/pickadate.js/pull/1140/files for the needed changes.

Comment: But increase the timeout to `100`.

Comment: @DanielRuf it's quite hard to find the places to change the logic based on https://github.com/amsul/pickadate.js/pull/1140/files these changes, on materialize.js file.

Comment: The focus / click handler has to be changed and a function added for the dethrottling.

Comment: Which materialize version do you use?

Comment: @DanielRuf I use this v0.100.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure, if this is a bulletproof solution but this works for me especially with clockpicker.
The version should be materializecss (v0.100.2). 
In materialize.js file, `Line No: 8913`

> ClockPicker.prototype.show = function (e) {

Just wrap setTimeout( 200 ms) inside this whole function, works well.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and solved like this way:

```
 $('.timepicker').on('mousedown',function(event){
event.preventDefault();})
```

Hope this will work it is working perfectly for me

Comment: Workes like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

@Subash
Hi there.

> ClockPicker.prototype.show = function (e) {
>
> Just wrap setTimeout( 200 ms) inside this whole function, works well.

For me it works only if I use arrow function cause then I keep "this" from previous context or you have to pass it through setTimeout.